# Total input prohibition signs in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I use a combobox, and i don't have value like ReadOnly.

How to block posibility to input any sign in this component.

I try something like, `OnKeyPress`

```
 if Key in ['a'..'z', 'A'..'Z'] then
    Key := #0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the `Style` property of the combobox to `csDropdownList`. Then the user can not type anything into it.

Comment: Aye. It's really annoying that this isn't the default value; it's usually the first thingt I do when dropping a combobox.